# Keeping programmed text in place when copying text from other applications

Tags: text, formatting

When I copy|paste text from Word into another program, such as RoboHelp, the formatting comes with it (bullets, font size, etc.). In my HTML table, I have it formatted for a certain font size, etc.). When I copy the text into the table, it overwrites the HTML coding in the table with the formatting in the pasted text. Is there a way that I can remedy this situation so that if I copy|paste information from another program that it keeps the formatting that is in my html table? I know this probably seems like a really easy issue, but It's really causing me a lot of problems. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide. If you have any sample code, please include it in your response as I'm desperate!

Answer (score 0):

Paste into your favorite basic to the bone text editor 
I like notepad.

This will remove all special formatting from the pasted text

you can now copy it from the text editor and paste it into your table.

Comment: Thank you, so there's no way you can do it programmatically with JavaScript or other code? Just wanted to be sure. Again, thanks!

Comment: With code howso? You said your copying from word into an html table. I would imaging your simply copy / pasting from word to your editor now right? i can't think of a way that you would perform this function with code.

Comment: The reason why I'm asking is that sometimes I've copied stuff from Notepad that had blank lines and when it pasted into the table the lines were gone.

Comment: That is strange, I've not encounters such behavior before. What kind of editor / ide are you pasting into?

Comment: Thank you for your help Sparky. Have a great day! I was using Notepad. It could just be a one-time thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are copying from Office programs there is a option when you right click selected text how you wish the text copied chose raw text and it should remove any indentations and styling.

Comment: Thanks! It didn't remove the bullets, though. I chose text only when pasting it. I didn't see any options when copying. Do you know where they're at?

Comment: The only option that i can think off right now is that you turn off bullets in settings while copying that should get rid of it i don't have copy of Office right now but i guess it can be turned off by right clicking and ticking show bullets.